# how to set the multiple tracker in google analytic

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/?hl=pl#MultipleCommands

```
_gaq.push(
  ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
  ['_trackPageview'],
  ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
  ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

in this code snippet, there is a ".b".
Where is the ".b" come from? How should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one account, you don't have to use anything:

```
_gaq.push(["_setAccount", ......]);
```

From there, if you use any more accounts, you give each one a name (any name that's valid in JS), and call its instructions like `name._doThing`.

You could track 8 accounts if you wanted - they just need 8 unique names, and you need to `_setAccount` each one to a different Google account.

Our company chose to use `primary` and `secondary` -- we even give the first account a name.

Comment: do I need to initial anything before I can start to use the name?

Comment: `["_setAccount", "U..........-1"]` *is* the initialization.  After you do that, it knows that whenever you use that name, it means that you want to use that action `_addTransaction`, `_trackPageview`, whatever...  ...with that account.  So initialize it with `_setAccount` and you're good to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The `b` is simply specified by Google as a way to indicate how to group commands.  I'd imagine you can use any string there.  You don't need to worry about it... just be consistent in what you use.